# Oracle OCI Change Notification -- should HOST= be the client machine?

Tags: oracle

I have an example program that works fine with one database and doesn't get a callback invocation on another database.

I noticed that in the working case `SELECT CALLBACK FROM USER_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION_REGS` returns a string that references the client IP address, which seems to intuitively match what the callback needs.

```
    (46, 4, 'net8://(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=172.16.252.1)(PORT=49406))?PR=0',
     0, 0, 1800, 'MH.CBDEMO')
    # 172.16.252.1 = client machine
```

In the busted case, the host string is filled in with the IP address of the database host.

```
  (271, 4, 'net8://(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=138.72.249.167)(PORT=50966))?PR=0',
   0, 0, 1800, 'MH.CBDEMO')
  # 138.72.249.167 = database host
```

So, two questions:

1. is it truly the case that the HOST= parm should refer to the OCI client?
2. what's the best way to figure out where the HOST= parm is being incorrectly filled in?

environment:

- client: Mac OSX, OCI, Python+cx_Oracle; database: 10.2.0.4.0
- good server:  linux on vmware, 10.2.0.4.0
- failing server: linux RAC,  10.2.0.4.0

Comment: Are the database servers the same environment, e.g., both windows or both *nix? Is the client using DHCP?

Comment: both linux, the failing server is part of a RAC cluster.  The client uses DHCP, but I think talks to the non-failing server over a vmware virtual network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle has confirmed that this is a bug in Oracle 10g RAC.  The field should be the client IP address, and it works on non-RAC systems.